# MVC Property of object in model is null on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know there are tons of posts similar to this, but I cannot seem to find the answer after much investigation.  On post back CompanySetting.NewSetting.SettingType and CompanySetting.NewSetting.SettingValue are null, despite putting text into the TextBoxFor fields and clicking submit.
Why is this?

Here is the view:

```
@model Project.Models.CompanySettingView
@using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label>Setting Type</label>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewSetting.SettingType, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SettingType" })

            <br />

             <label>Setting Value</label>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewSetting.SettingValue, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SettingValue" })

            <br />
          </div>
            <div style="float: right;">
            <button type="button" style="width:100px;" onclick="ClearFields()" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
            <button type="submit" style="width:100px;" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
           </div>
         </form>
                }
```

Receiving Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCompanySetting(CompanySettingView model)
{
...
}
```

CompanySettingView Class:

```
public class CompanySettingView
{
    public List<CompanySetting> Settings = new List<CompanySetting>();
    public CompanySetting NewSetting = new CompanySetting();
}
```

CompanySetting Class:

```
 public class CompanySetting
 {
     public int CompanySettingId { get; set; }
     public int CompanyId { get; set; }
     public string SettingType { get; set; }
     public string SettingValue { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Most likely to do with the nested object references (`NewSetting.SettingType`). You should probably flatten your viewmodel a bit more.

Comment: its to do with your object initialiser in the CompanySettingView.  Change those to properties and initialise them in your constructor (make sure the class has a default constructor) and all should be golden

Comment: in `CompanySettingView` why don't you `set` and `get` as well to make it simpler for you

Comment: @Slicksim thank you this was the problem

Comment: @user2884789 no problem, i've changed the comment to an answer.  If you could accept it, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: Dont think you can have a `form` within another `form` like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from Comment

its to do with your object initialiser in the CompanySettingView. Change those to properties and initialise them in your constructor (make sure the class has a default constructor) and all should be golden

Something like this:

```
public class CompanySettingView
{
    public List<CompanySetting> Settings { get; set; }
    public CompanySetting NewSetting { get; set; }

    public CompanySettingView()
    {
        this.Settings = new List<CompanySetting>();
        this.NewSetting = new CompanySetting();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out that only the name of the inputs, but not the id, will be used by the MVC modelbinder.